# ошибка при компиляции проекта С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

во  всех проектах с++ visual studio 2017 community при запуске программы появляется такое  окно

[image: окно уведомления]

если нажать Yes ,в error list появиться ошибка 
Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.

PS с С# проектами  все нормально такое только с С++

Comment: В параметрах проекта надо настроить Platform toolset(Набор инструментов платформы) - поставить 141, во вкладке C/C++ выключить режим совместимости. Возможно поможет.

Comment: У вас точно visual studio 2017? Почему тогда в сообщении написано 2010?

Comment: Точно , скриншот с инета